# cypress.json file not being recognized

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm new to cypress and have created my first project with a cypress.json file in the root directory.

[image: project directory]

The contents of this file are as follows:

```
{
    "projectId": "bdld4"
    "env":{
        "host": "http://localhost:8000",
        "email": "FakeUser@company.com",
        "password": "obviouslyNotaRealPassword"
    }
}
```

Within the integration folder I have a test case which is attempting to access those environment variables:

```
Cypress.env('host')
```

This returns undefined. I have also tried this in cypress.env.json and have also tried placing the cypress.json file one level above the Cypress folder.

To run the tests, i'm using `npx cypress open` and selecting the test from the gui. Am I running the tests incorrectly or should the file be placed elsewhere? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the picture you have posted, `cypress.json` is not placed the root. It is inside the `cypress` folder.

1. Either you can place the `cypress.json` one level up, I mean in the root of the project
2. Or, you can pass the config file path parameter in your script, like:

```
npx cypress open --config-file cypress/cypress.json
```

Answer (score 1):

just FYI - Cypress no longer supports cypress.json.  Use cypress.config.js instead.

I got an error when I had both a cypress.json and cypress.config.json file in my repo.